# Why pgfplots sometimes cycles markers and colors and sometimes doesn't?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Why the following examples differ considering line color and markerstyles?

First one draws black lines with no markers. Same thing happens when I add plots with `\addplot table [x index=0, y index=1]{data.dat}` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot[
  domain=-3e-3:3e-3,
  samples=201,
  ]
  {100+exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
  \addplot[
  domain=-3e-3:3e-3,
  samples=201,
  ]
  {exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

While this one cycles colors and markers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot plot coordinates {
        (7,     8.472)
        (31,    3.044)
        (111,   1.022)
        (351,   3.303)
    };
    \addplot plot coordinates {
        (9, 7.88)
        (49,    3.24)
        (209,   1.23)
        (769,   4.45)
    };
    \addplot plot coordinates {
        (11,    6.88)
        (71,    3.17)
        (351,   1.34)
        (14,  5.33)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get cycling effect when I add plots with `\addplot+` but I don't get why these examples differ.

This problem came up when I tried to visualize my data from text file. The first column contains x-axis data and the following columns contain data for y-axis. Data sets have 100 - 10 000 rows and 3 - 100 columns. What would be the best way the set color and linestyle for different columns?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268707

Comment: `+` means to append options. Without the `+` you are specifying ALL the options (once you provide one), which then no longer has the desired `cycle` option built in.