# empty options [] in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, optional-arguments

I am curious why specifying empty options (`[]`) is different from not specifying options at all. Eg consider the MWE which produces

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={thick}}
  \begin{axis}[legend entries={1, 2, 3}, legend pos={north west}, domain=0:2]
    \addplot[] {x/2)};
    \addplot[] {x/3};
    \addplot {x^2/4};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is the style different for the various plots? I could not find an explanation in the pgfplots manual.

Comment: No options = default options, empty options = replace default options with empty options.  I'm relatively sure that's documented.

Comment: If you want to append to the default options use `\addplot+[...]`

Comment: As Henri says, this is due to `\addplot` vs. `\addplot+`, which are described in section 4.3 of the manual.

Comment: apart from specifics about this tikz command it is generally true in latex that supplying an optional argument of [] is not the same as not supplying an option at all. They are only equivalent if the command is defined such that the default value of the argument is empty.

Comment: If there is an optional argument for the `\addplot` command the cycle list is not used for the plot. To change this behavior insert the `+` between \addplot and the optional argument. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268707/43317

Answer (score 1):

Empty brackets leads to writing `/.style={}` which resets that style. If you don't have any options you can leave out `[]` or place a plus sign `+[]` which leads to `/.append style`.

This behavior mimics the `\tikzstyle` macro from the old days of TikZ and its key system.

Comment: AFAIK `\addplot[]{...}; only disables the usage of the "cycle list". Therefore all plots in the MWE are still `thick`.